# Dashboard settings

Tags: jboss, rhq

I am using JBoss Operations Network 3.3 to monitor my JBoss application servers.

I have changed collection interval to my desired value.

For example, refer the pic:

[image: Dashboard[1]]

But in dashboard it's showing the results with the intervals of 8 minutes (by default). I want to change it to my desired values.

**Is there any option in dashboard to change those values?** I cannot find it.

pls refer the pic
[image: Dashboard2[2]]

Graph is showing the values with 8 minutes difference between the bars by default.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a graph in which the bars arent the measurements, but aggregated values - min, max and avg (line connects the averages).

Basically, you set the interval (not the collection interval) for which you want to display the data and then the interval is divided by 60 (this magic number is the number of bars displayed in the graph). So for instance, if you set the interval 'the last 1 hour', then each bar corresponds to 1 minute in that hour.

Now, if there was one or zero measurement in that minute, they are displayed as normal bars (no min, max, avg, because it doesn't make sense for just 1 value ~ 1 bar). On those position, where no measurements were taken, there is just nothing.

Your picture is different, you must have set the interval for the graph to some larger value, like 'last 8 hours', which is a default if I recall. So 8 hours / 60 = 8 minutes per 1 bar. That's why you see a bar per 8 minutes. But those bars are different ones. They visualize the aggregated values. I am not sure, how the calculation is done in this case, but for the sake of simplicity let's say, the collection interval is 1 minute and there is 1 bar per 8 minutes. It means 1 bar in the graph has to represent 8 measurement values. The minimum, maximum and average is calculated out of those 8 values and the bar in the graph is drawn.

for 1 bar:
Top of the darker blue - max. value
short horizontal line (dark blue or something) - avg
Bottom of the light blue - min. value

If your collection interval is 5 minutes and you want to see 1 bar per 1 collection of the metric, you have to set the interval of the graph to 5 hours (60 * 5). Just click on the `Custom` and set the range properly. Predefined `4 hours` would do the trick as well.

Comment: JIri , Thanks for your cool explanation but what i exactly need is , You have mentioned as 
"Your picture is different, you must have set the interval for the graph to some larger value, like 'last 8 hours', which is a default if I recall. So 8 hours / 60 = 8 minutes per 1 bar. That's why you see a bar per 8 minutes"

How do  I  set the interval for the graph to some value (say for example 5 hours). I don't find any options in JON dashboard.

Could you please assist??

Comment: I don't find any options like custom in the dashboard (JON)

Comment: iirc, there is a button with label "Custom", but for dashboard, it actually may not be there.